# Using Thread.Sleep to keep thread from hogging CPU

Tags: c#, multithreading

A common pattern I've seen (and have used myself) in order to keep a thread from hogging CPU time while processing data in a loop looks something like this:

```
foreach (itemInACollection)
{
    // do some processing on the item
    // ...
    // ...

    Thread.Sleep(1);
}
```

I don't particularly like this solution and would like to find a better way of accomplishing the same thing.

My question is two-fold, the first dealing with an existing code base that does not lend itself to much alteration and the second dealing with architecting a new solution.

1. Is there another way to prevent a thread from hogging the CPU when
   processing data in the way in the example above (i.e. when using a
   loop and iterating over each item)?
2. I realize that without providing more information the above example
   is quite broad, but are there other patterns that provide a better
   way of processing (synchronously) a large collection of data in a
   background thread?*

*Note: I realize that different data types may have different solutions more suitable to their implementation (and container types), but I was wondering if there might be a better pattern for processing a collection (e.g. array) of objects.

Comment: The answer to this question depend on whether the thread ALWAYS has some work to do for each iteration, or if it is polling for data.

Comment: Way to broad. What is `someCondition`? How long does this run? How long can you wait to do the next iteration?

Comment: You changed the `while` (waiting for a state) for a `foreach` (iterating) loop, a `Thread.Sleep()` does not make sense, please add a real world example.

Comment: A `foreach` is used for a determined number of items, so waiting for an external event in a loop does not make sense.

Comment: I feared that the question may not be clear enough - I'll vote to have it deleted and resubmit the question with a more concrete example at a later time. Thanks for taking the time to respond.

Comment: If the thread is using the CPU to do useful work, in what sense is it "hogging" the CPU? And if the thread is not using the CPU to do useful work, it should be fixed. Why did you use this pattern? What harm was caused by using the CPU to do the work you needed to do?!

Comment: Re the _... and have used myself_ part: what happens when you remove the Sleep() ? What is the actual problem behind this?

Comment: It is pretty fundamentally not the way the operating system works.  It abhors not using a resource that is readily available.  It is your job to tell it what it needs to know to do its job properly.  If that thread isn't doing anything that is time-critical then just tell it that it isn't important enough to be selected to execute on the processor.  Set the Thread.Priority property so, say, ThreadPriority.Lowest.  That produces the best balance, it still completes quickly if the machine doesn't have anything else to do *and* it cannot bog down another process.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Although I really wish I could, I unfortunately cannot go into the details, but basically I am dealing with a system that in essence is presenting me with only a single CPU core to work with. Processing data while simultaneously having to deal with incoming user requests on other threads (on the same core) is understandably resulting in some response issues (CPU usage is pretty much always 100% when running these data processing loops). I had similar issues years ago when coding against single core CPUs which is where I implemented the above pattern (not saying that it's right).

Comment: @RiaanDp I would suggest you use Async Await with Task.Yield instead of Thread.Sleep. Also Hans is correct that you should be using thread priority. However you have to be careful, as it sounds like you need to have some kind of back pressure on your processing code to prevent too many requests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why shouldn't your thread hog the CPU in the first place?
A thread is a (memory) costly object, run it flat out and then abandon it.

Managing system resources is not really the responsibility of your item-processing code.

When you do have a performance problem the management of this should be shifted to the code calling this.

When simply processing independent items, Parallel.ForEach might be a good choice. Why hog just 1 CPU when you can use all of them.

Comment: Although this doesn't directly provide a solution to my problem, I believe this answer will be of the most value to others stumbling across this post as it also addresses the issue of bad design resulting in the example code.

Answer (score 1):

The question is quite broad. I'll give you some pointers:

- Understand where CPU consumption comes from. Overwhelmingly will be cache miss and memory access cost, **not** instructions executed.  See [CPU Caches and Why You Care - Scott Meyers](http://www.aristeia.com/TalkNotes/ACCU2011_CPUCaches.pdf)
- Cap the process available resources. Use a [Job Object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684161(v=vs.85).aspx), set a [CPU limit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh448384(v=vs.85).aspx) and then start the process in this job. This will be enforced by OS and the process cannot exceed the set limits (its thread will simply not be scheduled by the OS). A poor man equivalent is [`start /low`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770297.aspx).
- Read this series: [Designing Applications for High Performance](http://blogs.technet.com/winserverperformance/archive/2008/04/25/designing-applications-for-high-performance-part-1.aspx), [Part 2](http://blogs.technet.com/b/winserverperformance/archive/2008/05/21/designing-applications-for-high-performance-part-ii.aspx) and [Part 3](http://blogs.technet.com/b/winserverperformance/archive/2008/06/26/designing-applications-for-high-performance-part-iii.aspx).
- Learn to profile apps to identify bottlenecks: [Beginners Guide to Performance Profiling](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182372.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for providing some alternatives for approaching this issue.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a bunch of work to do, you should just do it. This doesn't typically create any problems so there's typically nothing to solve.